# T-SQL: Query across tables converting rows to columns?

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server 2012.

Straight to the point, this is what I'm trying to do:

**User table**

```
id   username fullname
---- -------- ----------------------
1    test0001 Test User #1
2    test0002 Test User #2
3    test0003 Test User #3
4    test0004 Test User #4
```

**Flags table**

```
id  name       description
--- ---------- -------------------------------------------
1   isActive   true if user is currently active
2   isAdmin    true if user can do Admin things
3   canEdit    true if user can can edit
```

**UserFlags table**

```
user flag
---- ----
1    1
1    2
1    3
2    1
2    3
3    1

(user = FK to user.id, flag = FK to flag.id)
```

**Desired result**

```
userId username isActive isAdmin canEdit
------ -------- -------- ------- -------
1      test0001 1        1       1
2      test0002 1        0       1
3      test0003 1        0       0
4      test0004 0        0       0
```

In short I want to convert each flag in the flags table into a column with the `name` field used as the column header. Then I want a row for each user, with a boolean in each column indicating whether they have that particular flag.

This needs to be able to adapt - e.g. if another flag is added, the result of the query should have another column with that flag's name as its title.

I'd prefer to do this in a view, but I'd be OK with a table-valued function.

I haven't done anything like this before so I'm not even sure where to start - I can do a full join on the tables and end up with a row per user per flag, but I then want to fold that all down into a single row per user.

**EDIT** One of the key points is "able to adapt" - the best scenario would be a query that *automatically pulls in all currently defined flags* from the flags table when building the response. Having to edit the query isn't necessarily bad, but consider the instance where an admin is allowed to add a new flag to the system. It's easy to INSERT a new flag, it's much harder to autonomously edit a stored query to reflect that. If that's simply not possible to do, then an explanation as to why would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You would need to PIVOT the last table. What have you tried so far?

Comment: All I'm doing right now is calling a UDF I wrote that asks "does user X have flag Y". I then call that function over and over for each user, each flag and basically end up with a table with one row per user per flag with a boolean. As I said in the following comment, all of the solutions here do work but require the query itself to be modified to handle more flags. I'm looking at PIVOT to see if it's in any way possible to accomplish it with that.

Comment: there are two answers which will help you here: there's a PIVOT answer from Kannan, and a simpler non-PIVOT answer from lostmylogin. Both should solver your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select u.id, u.username, f.[name] from #user u
    left join  #userflags uf
    on uf.[user] = u.id
    left join #flags f
    on uf.flag = f.id
) a
pivot (count([name]) for [name] in ([isActive],[isAdmin],[canEdit])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+
| id | username | isActive | isAdmin | canEdit |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+
|  1 | test0001 |        1 |       1 |       1 |
|  2 | test0002 |        1 |       0 |       1 |
|  3 | test0003 |        1 |       0 |       0 |
|  4 | test0004 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
+----+----------+----------+---------+---------+
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/VKATS51824)

Updated my query if you have dynamic list of flags as below:

```
Declare @cols1 varchar(max)
Declare @query nvarchar(max)

Select @cols1 = stuff((select distinct ','+QuoteName([name]) from #flags for xml path('')),1,1,'')

Select @query = '   Select * from (
        Select u.id, u.username, f.[name] from #user u
        left join  #userflags uf
        on uf.[user] = u.id
        left join #flags f
        on uf.flag = f.id
    ) a
    pivot (count([name]) for [name] in (' + @cols1 + ')) p '

Exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Your response is the most concise, but all of the responses here would require editing the query if a new flag is added. Is it simply not possible to automatically pull in the flags from the flags table?

Comment: Then you need to add dynamic query to add that flag as well. Updated my query accordingly

Comment: This looks very promising. I also found an article http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-dynamic-way that seems to explain this sort of thing. @Eli got me on the right path with PIVOT. Will try your solution!

Answer (score 2):

If you dont like `pivot` function like me; you can use the `SUM` `IIF` method like this

```
SELECT u.id
    , username
    , SUM(IIF(flag = 1, 1, 0)) AS isActive
    , SUM(IIF(flag = 2, 1, 0)) AS isAdmin
    , SUM(IIF(flag = 3, 1, 0)) AS canEdit
FROM User u
LEFT JOIN UserFlags uf ON uf.[user] = u.id
GROUP BY u.id
    , username
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a case statement and subquery or with a pivot. They both essentially do the same thing. This includes the DDL for the tables I made for testing.

```
declare @user_tbl table (
id int,
username nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT @user_tbl VALUES
(1,'test0001'),
(2,'test0002'),
(3,'test0003'),
(4,'test0004')


declare @userflags_tbl table(
userid int,
flag int
)

INSERT @userflags_tbl VALUES
(1,1),
(1,2),
(1,3),
(2,1),
(2,3),
(3,1)

declare @flags_tbl table(
id int
)

INSERT @flags_tbl VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3)

SELECT
    userid,
    username,
    MAX(isActive) AS isActive,
    MAX(isAdmin) AS isAdmin,
    MAX(canEdit) AS canEdit
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_tbl.id AS userid,
        user_tbl.username,
        CASE
            WHEN userflags_tbl.flag = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS isActive,
        CASE
            WHEN userflags_tbl.flag = 2 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS isAdmin,
        CASE
            WHEN userflags_tbl.flag = 3 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS canEdit
    FROM @user_tbl user_tbl
    LEFT JOIN @userflags_tbl userflags_tbl ON
        user_tbl.id = userflags_tbl.userid
    LEFT JOIN @flags_tbl flags_tbl ON
        userflags_tbl.flag = flags_tbl.id
    )tbl
GROUP BY
    userid,
    username


SELECT
    userid,
    username,
    ISNULL([1],0) AS isActive,
    REPLACE(ISNULL([2],0),2,1) AS isAdmin,
    REPLACE(ISNULL([3],0),3,1) AS canEdit
FROM (
    SELECT
        user_tbl.id AS userid,
        user_tbl.username,
        userflags_tbl.flag
    FROM @user_tbl user_tbl
    JOIN @userflags_tbl userflags_tbl ON
        user_tbl.id = userflags_tbl.userid
    JOIN @flags_tbl flags_tbl ON
        userflags_tbl.flag = flags_tbl.id
    ) tbl
PIVOT (
    MAX(flag)
    FOR flag IN ([1],[2],[3])
    ) AS PivotTable
```